# multi-select image switcher for product configuration. how to do?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, bundled-product, multiselect

Tell me how to implement the next task. I have a set product. First, choose the color of the base, then the color of the product edges, and then you need to make it so that the client could choose several options, (like multi-selection) of the goods, or one. The choice should be made by clicking on the image. The problem is that in the standard version of the item you can select only one value. Thanks for the help.